# Write a Macro to Edit an Individual Comment in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

So far I have a custom context menu that appears when I right click a comment allowing me to run a Macro in word.

How do I write my macro to replace the comment's text with the word "Ignore"?

There will be numerous comments some that I will want the macro to run on and others I won't so I need it to specifically change the comment that I right click on.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've found the solution so I'm posting in case anyone else has the same problem.

First you'll need a custom shortcut menu for your right click, you can find out how to build this here: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_shortcut_menu.html

Then you need to create a macro with the following code:

```
Sub ARIgnoreComment0001()
If Selection.Information(wdInCommentPane) = True Then
    Dim Comment
    For Each Comment In ActiveDocument.Comments
        If Comment.Range.Start <= Selection.Start And Comment.Range.End >= Selection.Range.End Then
            Comment.Range.Text = "Ignore this comment!!!"
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you can right click a comment and replace it's text with one click of a macro :)